# Chrome extension form input text is blank on submit

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension that downloads a bunch of items from links, the main logic is in my `download.js` file and I want to be able to specify in which downloads subfolder I'd like to bundle them all but the value of the input field seems to be empty. Here's my code so far

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Download CVs</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="folderForm">
      Subdir of downloads:
      <input type="text" id="folder">
      <input type="submit" id="download" value="Download CVs">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function bundleItems() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'download.js'
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var downloadButton = document.getElementById('download');
  downloadButton.addEventListener('click', bundleItems);
});

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(logs) {
  var folder = document.getElementById('folder').value;

  logs.map(function(log) {
    chrome.downloads.download({
      url: log.attachment.link,
      filename: folder + '/' + log.attachment.filename
    });
  });
});
```

I'm sending information from `download.js` to `popup.js` and everything works if I try to download it in downloads, so I feel posting my `download.js` file will be useless. However, if I try to display the `folder` variable, it's empty. I've searched for lots of other posts on the same issue and none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot **submit** to a Chrome extension page. There is no web server to process your POST request in this case. Doing so simply reloads the document (clearing your value from the form).

You need to *prevent* submitting instead, by specifying `type="button"` for your button.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still blank after changing it to button

Comment: I've tested it a few more times, mostly it works and sometimes the whole extension bugs out, saying I don't have permission, but I guess it's good enough :) thanks

Comment: You should check that `executeScript` succeeded (by checking `chrome.runtime.lastError` in a callback); not all URLs are accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I would add preventDefault() on submit button.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: That would solve the problem as well, but in a more convoluted way. "Let's make this a submit button, and then refuse to let it submit" vs "Let's not make this a submit button".