# chrome.storage not saving data (chrome was used before it was defined)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am following a youtube tutorial for making chrome extensions.

This is the **Manifest file**:

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name":"Budget Manager",
    "version":"1.0",
    "description":"This extension tracks your overall spendings.",
    "icons":{
        "128":"icon128.png",
        "48":"icon48.png",
        "16":"icon16.png"
    },
    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon":"icon16.png",
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Budget Manager</title>
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="popup.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Budget Manager</h1>
        <h2>Total Spend: <span id="total">0</span></h2>
        <h2>Limit: <span id="limit"></span></h2>
        <h3>Enter Amount</h3>
        <input type="text" id="amount"/>
        <input type="submit" id="spendAmount" value="Spend">
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
$(function() {   
    chrome.storage.sync.get('total', function (budget) {
        $('#total').text(budget.total);
    });
    $('#spendAmount').click(function() {
        chrome.storage.sync.get('total', function (budget) {
            var newTotal = 0;
            if (budget.total) {
                newTotal += parseInt(budget.total);
            }

            var amount = $('amount').val();
            if(amount) {
                newTotal += parseInt(amount);
            }

            chrome.storage.sync.set({'total': newTotal});

            $('#total').text(newTotal);
            $('#amount').val('');
        });
    });
});
```

I am getting errors like:
'chrome' was used before it was defined  -->    chrome.storage.sync.get('total', function (budget) {
Missing 'use strict' statement  -->    chrome.storage.sync.get('total', function (budget) {
'$' was used before it was defined  -->    $(function){

Also another beginner question. Why are we using chrome.storage anyways? I mean if we don't have to sync. Why can't I just use normal variables to store the data.

Comment: Where are you getting these errors - in IDE or browser? Also, you can store in variables if you don't need the values to persist after the popup is closed.

Comment: @wOxxOm These errors are in the IDE. Although the **Total Spend** in the popup is also not updating. After I enter value in the input field and click submit, the **Total Spend** in the popup still remains 0

Comment: That's because the browser has no server so the page cannot be submitted: it simply reloads the page losing all data. Use a normal button and click event listener. As for IDE, you need to configure it like e.g. eslint has an environment for webextensions, or simply add `chrome` and `$` to globals.

Comment: wOxxOm clearly identified the problem with the code, and I happen to remember it's a duplicate. For IDE errors, it's simply unaware of Chrome API / jQuery - and it's IDE-dependent how to make it aware. As to why use the Storage API - every time the popup is visually closed it's actually unloaded as a page (losing all JS state), and freshly loaded again next time it's shown, so if you need persistence you need _some_ storage.

Comment: @Xan So I tried changing to type: "button" like you had mentioned. But its still not working.

Comment: You also have a typo `$("amount")` without `#`. Perhaps at this point its best to reopen, as there are multiple problems (and multiple questions in one - you should avoid it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First, the non-errors

> I am getting errors like:
>
> 'chrome' was used before it was defined -->
>   Missing 'use strict' statement -->
>   '$' was used before it was defined -->

Those are your IDE's *warnings*. They are harmless in this case (e.g. your IDE simply isn't aware of Chrome or jQuery API) and not related to your problems. How to fix (or silence) them is IDE-dependent.

Note that you should not rely on them only; after all, the **browser** is the final "consumer" of your code and has the final say. Take a look at the [debugging tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) for extensions to see how to access Chrome's console for your code.

### Now, for errors

1. Using `submit` controls in Chrome extensions doesn't make sense; all they achieve is simply reloading the page. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176525/chrome-extension-form-input-text-is-blank-on-submit) as the canonical source, but TL;DR is to use input type `button`.
2. You have a typo in your code:

   ```
   var amount = $('amount').val();
   ```

   This should have `#amount`. Sadly, jQuery simply returns `undefined` here instead of throwing a visible error.

### Next, the "why"

Chrome extension popups do not survive being closed; it's not simply hidden until next time you open, it's opened *freshly* every time. Kind of like refreshing the page. So JS state does not survive - you can't keep data there and expect it to still be there next time.

So you need *some* form of storage for persistence (unless you're fine with everything resetting when the popup closes). `chrome.storage` API is the "most native" choice - though in your case using `sync` is probably overkill, you can get away with `local`.

It's important to understand the up- and downsides of various storage APIs. For example, `sync` can only store small amounts of data and can't be written to very frequently. Here's [a good overview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24279495/934239).

Comment: Meta-advice: for your next SO question, keep those in mind: 1) asking multiple separate questions in one isn't good for SO format, 2) you _must_ state what isn't working (not just error messages, but what's the behavior you're seeing vs expecting).

Comment: Thank you so much for all the explanation. This was really helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome! I forgot the link to the debugging tutorial, edited it in now: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging