# How to call the function in Chrome extension to using Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-chrome-extension, angular2-forms

I am using the `login()` function in my Chrome extension. I am trying to call the function when form submit. But, the function is not called in a Chrome extension. But, when I run the project in an Angular way the function is called.

This is my HTML code.

```html
  <form  (ngSubmit)="login()" id="SignIn">
```

and my ts code is

```js
login(){
    alert("form submitted");
  }
```

I referred to the following blog link [angular 2 chrome extension](https://www.sitepoint.com/chrome-extension-angular-2/)

and my manifest file is

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "chrome extension",
  "description": "This extension will used to simplify the project",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://example.com/*",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

I want to handle the events with in a component.i don't want to the another script file.

Comment: actually your form is with button for submit ? try <button (click)="login()"></button>

Comment: i am trying to  <input class="signup-form-button " type="submit" id="signin" (click)="login()" value="Sign In">.But it also not working

Comment: in your console there is no error ?

Comment: i don't have  any console error.

Comment: try to re install and verify that you imported FormModule in your appmodule

Comment: You're looking at the wrong console. Right click the popup, then Inspect. You'll see an error about inline code not allowed in html. I don't know angular, but in normal js you can use addEventListener.

Comment: What *exactly* is shown in the [various appropriate consoles for your extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982/3773011) when you load and execute your extension?

Comment: You will probably also encounter: [Chrome extension form input text is blank on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40176525)